# ArrayList wont display its elements

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my Object class:

```
public class Book {

   private String title;
   private int year;

   public Book(String title, int year){
      title = this.title;
      year = this.year;
   }

    public String getTitle(){return title;}
    public int getYear(){return year;}

    public String toString(){return (title + "\t" + year);}
}
```

the application class will read from the BookInput.txt which already has data of book title and publish year in it and will transfer the data into an arraylist called BookList. one book title and its publish year will be record in one index (which mean there's two data in one index, a string and an int)

This is my application class:

```
    ArrayList <Book> BookList = new ArrayList();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("bookInput.txt"));

    String str = br.readLine();
    while (str!=null){
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,";");
        String title = st.nextToken();
        String yr = st.nextToken();
        int year = Integer.parseInt(yr);
        Book b1 = new Book (title,year);
        BookList.add(b1);
        str = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < BookList.size(); i++){
        Book b2 = BookList.get(i);
        System.out.println("#" + (i+1) + " " + b2.getTitle() + " , " + b2.getYear());
    }
```

my display will come out as null for all of the title and 0 for all publish year. it can be compile without any error.

Comment: especially when just starting to learn: try to start correctly. Don't use StringTokenizer. This class has been deprecated for years, and should not be used. Use the split method of the String class instead

Comment: `this` is the actual instance (not the method); `this.title` is the title field of the instance not the parameter of the method... so `title = this.title` is setting the parameter and not the instance field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set object's attributes the other way around and you can consider to make private fields as `final` (in this case you get a compilation error in case of final values are not properly initialized in the constructor):

```
private final String title;
private final int year;

public Book(String title, int year){
   this.title = title;
   this.year = year;
}
```

Comment: marking them as final might lead to issues when this class, or a subclass, is not supposed to be immutable

Comment: Final is optional but helps to find such erros

Comment: @Stultuske Private fields are not visible to a subclass.

Comment: @ttulka doesn't mean the original class can't have protected scope setters in the future.

Comment: @Stultuske Sure, but it doesn't in this case. I find immutability a good practice. Anyway thank you for the comment - it's something to consider by designing the class.

Comment: @ttulka we don't really know whether it is in this case (or whether it will be). SO only requires a minimal example of what goes wrong where, the setters are not relevant for it, and might be ommitted.) Now, just as you, I assume that's not the case, but that won't mean setters might not be added later on

Comment: @Stultuske yes, this is just a note. We do not know full scope.

Comment: @Stultuske I changed the answer slightly to make it clear.